# Type definitions for Knockout v3.4.0 failure with extend

Tags: webstorm, definitelytyped

I installed the External Library into the newest Webstorm today.

http_github.com_DefinitelyTyped_DefinitelyTyped_raw_master_knockout_knockout.d.ts

```
    this.roles = ko.observableArray(_d.roles).extend({trackChanges: {initial: false}});
    this.type = ko.observable(_d.type || 'user').extend({trackChanges: {initial: false}});
    this.enabled = ko.observable(_d.enabled).extend({trackChanges: {initial: false}});
    this.salutation = ko.observable(_d.salutation).extend({
        trackChanges: {initial: false},
        validator: {required: false}
    });
```

In the first line, the extend Method is not resolved.
In the second and third line, it is resolved.
In the fourth line it is again unresolved.

Is this a known Issue and if yes, it's WebStorm or DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by not using DefinitelyTyped any more.

Instead I downloaded all the uncompressed JavaScript library versions that I need in my project, stored them in a separate folder and configured WebStorm to use them.

[image]

This works perfectly well...